# Table Data Repetition - MySQL

Tags: mysql

What would I do with this repetitive data in cost_center_code column?

[image]

This is my query:

```
select c.cost_center_code, a.department_description,  
SUM(a.cdr_charge_amount)  
from cdr_departments a  
join departments b ON a.department_id = b.department_id  
join cost_centers c ON b.site_id = c.site_id  
group by a.department_description
```

Comment: `cost_center_code` is neither aggregated nor used for grouping.  While MySQL [allows it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html), the result is unpredictable.

Comment: When i removed the group by, this is the result:   42040001 Admin Base Opex 11487815.02

Comment: I have not suggested removing `GROUP BY`.